# couchapp push gives [Errno 22] Invalid Argument

Tags: python, couchdb, couchapp

I've just installed `couchapp` from the instructions and have gone through the Getting Started tutorial. When I run `couchapp push` I get an error like this:

```
    2012-06-23 14:05:08 [CRITICAL] unknown error [[Errno 22] Invalid argument]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 48, in dispatch
    return _dispatch(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 92, in _dispatch
    return fun(conf, conf.app_dir, *args, **opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/commands.py", line 76, in push
    dbs = conf.get_dbs(dest)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/config.py", line 146, in get_dbs
    return [Database(dburl, use_proxy=use_proxy) for dburl in dburls]
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/client.py", line 223, in __init__
    self.res.head()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/restkit/resource.py", line 122, in head
    params_dict=params_dict, **params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/couchapp/client.py", line 143, in request
    raise RequestFailed("unknown error [%s]" % str(e))
RequestFailed: unknown error [[Errno 22] Invalid argument]
```

I'm on OS X 10.6.8, CouchDB is already setup with admins, and the `.couchapprc` file has the default db set as `http://user:pass@localhost:5984/mydb`. I've followed the instructions from [couchapp.org](http://couchapp.org) for a Homebrew install. The only thing I can figure is that this is a Python-related problem, but I don't know Python and can't seem to figure out why this thing is failing. Any help tracking down this problem and fixing it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I get the exact same thing. Here are the commands I used to install CouchApp, get the example Sofa app, and push: https://gist.github.com/3137964

Comment: Can you look at the CouchDB logs and see if couchapp is connecting to the server?  Is anything getting sent to the server or does it just fail right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens to me it usually means SOMEWHERE....SOMEHOW, some JSON in the _doc folder is formatted badly, and it could be on a weird level. So like two _ids or a _rev where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem and solved it, by downgrade to other version.

https://github.com/downloads/couchapp/couchapp/couchapp-0.8.1-macosx.zip

Seems the best solution, for now.

Comment: I had this problem too after upgrading from 0.7, and also solved it by a downgrade. I found that this version works for me: https://github.com/downloads/couchapp/couchapp/couchapp-1.0.0-macosx.zip